# Update array by using array index in python

Tags: python, arrays

How to use an array index to update a value in array.The compiler keep mention Index Error:list assignment index out of range.

Array Value before change:

[10,0,9,1]

Array value after update:

[9,0,9,1]

```
x = int(input("Input a number"))

drinkstock = [10,0,9,1]

z=int(drinkstock[x]-1)

for y in drinkstock:

   if drinkstock.index(y)==x:

      drinkstock[y]=z

      print(y)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing the index in 'for' loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-for-loops)

Comment: It's not clear what you even want to accomplish, tip: *don't provide code that depends on user input you can avoid it, especially if you **don't provide the input***

Comment: if you just want to update the array value, why can't you just type `drinkstock[x]=z`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The for y in drinkstock allows you to access each number inside the array drinkstock.

So you would get:

```
y = 10 #first iteration
y = 0 #second iteration
y = 9 #third iteration
y = 1 #fourth iteration
```

So then when you do:

```
drinkstock[y] = z
```

you are trying to access the 10th index in drinkstock which does not exist.

Instead, you can do:

```
for i in range(len(drinkstonk)):
    drinkstonk[i] = z
```

Not sure why you are trying to loop through the entire array though since it looks like you only updated one index value.

Comment: Also, the op is expecting the output to be `[9,0,9,1]`, and so, it should be `if i==x: drinkstonk[i] = z` inside the for-loop. And the last line should be `print(drinkstonk)` instead of `print(y)`

Answer (score 1):

cause this list length is 4 is's index just can choose from 0-3.

maybe you can do this

```py
x = int(input("Input a number"))

drinkstock = [10,0,9,1]

if x in drinkstock:
    index = drinkstock.index(x)
    drinkstock[index] = x-1
print(drinkstock)
```

use list.index() to get x's index in drinkstock to update value

Comment: This would work for this particular example but I think it may fail if drinksock happens to have repeated values and another number other than zero is entered as input. For example, if drinkstock happens to be `[10,0,10,1]` and if the input value happens to be 2 then it would print `[9,0,10,1]` instead of `[10,0,9,1]`.